# Matching 'Capitalized' words in Vim

Tags: regular-expression, gvim, syntax

I'm trying to use the following regex to match 'Capitalized' words:

`"\l\@<!\<\u\w\+"`

Which matches 'Main' and 'Canvas' in:

`public class Main extends Canvas`

Or another example, matches all occurrences of 'Bitmap':

`public Bitmap b = new Bitmap();`
And InputHandler in:

`addKeyListener(new InputHandler())`

This works fairly nice when used in search mode but not completely when using `syntax match` in a syntax file, where the command would be:

`syntax match Capitalized "\l\@<!\<\u\w\+"`
This does not match anything that is inside parenthesis. Take one example from above:

`addKeyListener(new InputHandler())`
InputHandler is matched in search mode, but not from a syntax match command.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Copied your example lines, and used your "syntax match..." (also copy-past). Added "hi def link Capitalized Error" to get some color. It works for me. Im using (g)vim 8.1.565.

Comment: I think the answer you seek is not about the regex matching, but about how syntax specifications work. I would guess that the problem is related to the use of `contains` and `contained`, in that the parantheses are matched by a syntax region command, and everything that can be matched inside the parantheses must be defined with properly defined `containedin=...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so very much @KarlYngveLervåg for pointing out [`:h :syn-containedin`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3asyn-containedin), it leaded me towards the solution:

```
syntax match Capitalized "\l\@<!\<\u\w\+" containedin=parenGroup
```

Where `parenGroup` in my case is a 'syntax region' that also contains the top cluster. More specifically the exact solution was (for java.vim):

```
syntax match Capitalized "\l\@<!\<\u\w\+" containedin=javaParenT
```

No need to define a new region or crazy parenthesis matching.

Note: If your parent region definition doesn't include the top cluster this might not work outside parenthesis!

Summarizing, vim syntax definitions has some gotchas!

Again , thanks!

---

Update!
My previous solution would not match `KeyEvent` in:

```
if (input.keys[KeyEvent.VK_A])
```

Now changing the syntax specification to (java only!):

```
syntax match capitalInParen transparent matchgroup=javaParen start="(" end="\]\w\+)" contains=@javaTop
syntax match Capitalized "\l\@<!\<\u\w\+" containedin=capitalInParent
```

This is not perfect but still much better than the last one.